# Public wifi on public bus blocks all udp packets

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, udp

Our public bus service gives us free WiFi but all UDP packets are blocked because I couldn't play online games that uses the udp protocol or make voip calls on my android phone. I ran a test on the network seeing which ports are open and it showed that the UDP ports are blocked. Is there a way around this?

Comment: `Our public bus service gives us free WiFi but all UDP packets are blocked because I couldn't play online games that uses the udp protocol or make voip calls on my android phone` - Well you probably shouldn't look a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: I don't understand this figure of speech but I'm guessing you're trying to say don't ask for more when its free? I was just trying to know if there was a way around it and I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not... really.

You could try running all your traffic through a VPN connection, and that might work, depending on how you configure it, but basically, if a network blocks [whatever], you can't use [whatever] on that network.

If the free wifi on the bus blocks UDP, you're not going to be able to use UDP, and trying to get around it is probably a ToS (terms of service) violation, in addition to a generally futile effort, especially without significant technical expertise.

Comment: Good answer, just to add that even using VPN (such as routing through your private VPN at home) would most likely be too flaky for UDP, especially for VOIP.

Comment: @CharlesH Yeah, probably.  However, I've has some success with that approach and some commercial VPN services, so I figured it bears mentioning as something that *might* work.

Comment: Thanks I'll try a VPN, my friend has one that he is willing to share with me.